# Unification of the design. Be or not to be?

Tags: web, usability

There is a site with responsive design. The main menu and logo take almost the whole first screen on mobile devices. The site owner considers it's not OK and wants to use a menu like a button (like on starbucks.com site, mobile version). But not for the whole site. Only for several pages.

In my opinion it's not OK to use different types of navigation on different site pages because it can confuse site visitors. I suggest either to leave it as is or replace the current menu with the new menu on all pages.
How can I argue in favour of this? Is it a normal practice to use different navigation methods on different pages or it is not recommended? Are there maybe any articles on the matter?

Comment: I don't think it is an answer, but it is interresting to read: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/responsive-nav-patterns/